# Add missing ServerName to httpd.conf file using sed

Tags: linux, sed

I have the following virtual hosts in httpd.conf file

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
    ## could be comments
    could be any line
    could be any line
    could be any line
    </VirtualHost>

    <VirtualHost *:80>
       could be any line
    ## could be comments
    could be any line
    could be any line
    could be any line
    could be any line
    could be any line
    </VirtualHost>

    <VirtualHost *:80>
## may have comments
    ServerName ppp.com
        could be any line
    could be any line
    could be any line
  </VirtualHost>

    <VirtualHost *:443>
   ## could be empty
    ServerName zzz.com
    could be any line
    could be any line
    could be any line
    </VirtualHost>
```

I'm trying to add "ServerName abc.com" to every virtual host which doesn't have a ServerName already setup.

I was trying to do it in sed, and I'm not getting anywhere .. any help ?

This is what I have so far ...

```
sed '/^[ \t]*<VirtualHost/,/^[ \t]*<\/VirtualHost/{
/^ServerName/!{
   /<VirtualHost/{
     /^/a\ServerName abc.com

   }
  }
}' httpd.conf
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think maybe awk is better suited to this task. Here is `add-server-name.awk`:

```
/<VirtualHost/ { named=0; indent=substr($0,1,match($0,/<VirtualHost/)-1) }
/^[[:blank:]]*ServerName[[:blank:]]*/ { named=1; }
/<\/VirtualHost>/ { if (!named) print indent "ServerName abc.com" }
{ print }
```

Usage:

```
awk -f add-server-name.awk httpd.conf
```

Comment: works perfectly, just made some modifications to the regex to get the leading whitespace. Yes the ServerName can be the last line in the VH

Comment: @user2045331: Based on your clarification of the requirements, it's been simplified and handles indentation.

Answer (score 2):

Using sed:

```
sed '/<VirtualHost/{
       :a N;/<\/VirtualHost>/!b a;
       /ServerName/!s!\(</VirtualHost>\)!ServerName abc.com\n\1!
}' input
```

I don't think awk has any advantages over sed for this particular problem.

Comment: `sed '/<VirtualHost/{
       :a N;/<\/VirtualHost>/!b a;
       /ServerName/!s!\([[:blank:]]*\)\(</VirtualHost>\)!\1ServerName abc.com\n\1\2!` to prevent it from screwing up the indentation of the closing tag.

Answer (score 0):

Awk is going to be a much better help on this. It deals with multiple lines much better, plus httpd.conf is already in a record format.

```
# adServer.awk
BEGIN { RS = "</VirtualHost>" }  #separate records on end of a Virtual Host
$0 /ServerName/ { print $0 $RS}  # used for records with a name

$0 ~ /ServerName/ {   # else
    for  ( i = 1; i <= NF; i ++ ) {
        print $i
        if ( $i /<VirtualHost.*>/ ) {
            print "ServerName abc.com\n"
        }
    }
    print $RS
}
```

Comment: This is a neat idea, but not guaranteed to work on every system. *The first character of the string value of RS shall be the input record separator; a <newline> by default. If RS contains more than one character, the results are unspecified.* -- POSIX.1-2008

Comment: Fair enough.  Since I use gawk as my implementation, regex work as expected in the RS variable.